# Join Multiple tables, then show data from one of the tables as separate columns based on CASE criteria

Tags: mysql

I have been able to join multiple tables from different databases but I am getting stuck with how to show data from one of the tables into separate columns using case criteria.

```
select p.ProductID as pid,
    s.ItemCode as icode,
    s.ItemDescription,
    s.UOM,
    s.AvgCost,
    b.ST as stockAvl,
    CASE WHEN c.saledate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW() THEN SUM(c.qty) ELSE 0 END as s60,
    CASE WHEN c.saledate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND NOW() THEN SUM(c.qty) ELSE 0 END as s90,
    CASE WHEN c.saledate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 180 DAY) AND NOW() THEN SUM(c.qty) ELSE 0 END as s180,
    CASE WHEN c.saledate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND NOW() THEN SUM(c.qty) ELSE 0 END as s365
FROM db_inventory.StockMain_T s
left outer join db_inventory.stkbalance_T b on s.ItemCode=b.itemid
left outer join db_main.SaleItems_T c on c.ItemID=s.ItemCode
left outer join db_inventory.ProductMaster_T p on p.ProductID=s.ProdID
group by icode
order by pid
```

The above query works but is inconsistent with results. The columns s60,s90,s180 and s365 do not show complete data. The result shows data for only a few items and not for all items whereas there is data recorded into the SaleItems_T table for those items too but the result shows 0 for those. Can't seem to understand what is it that i'm doing wrong in the query.

Here is the result of the query. For simplification, i have removed a few columns from the original query above and kept 5 columns.
The ttlsales shows sum of all sales in the database history since beginning.
s300 and s900 are blank except one item. s9000 is also the entire history when used as

```
NOW()-INTERVAL 9000 DAY
```

so it shows the entire history as well. Issues is with columns s300 and s900 which do not show data whereas data exists in the saleitems table.

[image]

Comment: Please make a smape database in dbfiddle, these conditional statements are sometimes tricky

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate on the returned value of each `CASE` statement:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN c.saledate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) AND NOW() THEN c.qty ELSE 0 END) as s60,
SUM(CASE WHEN c.saledate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 90 DAY) AND NOW() THEN c.qty ELSE 0 END) as s90,
SUM(CASE WHEN c.saledate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 180 DAY) AND NOW() THEN c.qty ELSE 0 END) as s180,
SUM(CASE WHEN c.saledate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND NOW() THEN c.qty ELSE 0 END) as s365
```